# Comparable (against Comparator) for natural order sorting

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

Why is it suggested to use Comparable (against Comparator) for natural order sorting?
Anyway, I will be overriding my compareTo( from Comparable), why shouldn't I use it for other order search?

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* suggested that you don't use *a* Comparator for a "natural ordering".

What is suggested, is that Comparable be *only* used for the "natural ordering" (if there is one).

Comparable can only be implemented once and must behave well with equals, etc.

Comment: My question is, why Comparable be only used for natural ordering ?

Comment: You can use Comparator for natural ordering. Comparable should only be used for natural ordering. If you want to know why Comparable should only be used for natural ordering, then this is a *very* repeat question